# ARCore Sceneform create a Ruler between 2 points

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Currently I'm able to create a line between 2 anchor nodes and calculate their distance.
I've seen some apps in which they produce a Ruler between 2 points instead of a plain line. Just wondering how is that possible. Trying to search for a starting point but totally clueless. Please let me know if anyone has any slightest idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple node at the midpoint between the two anchor nodes with the renderable as the ruler and then scale this renderable between the two anchor nodes according to the distance between the two.